# IF statement ain't working with multiple OR operators in IF condition

Tags: c#, if-statement, radio-button, logical-operators

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (radioButton1.Checked || radioButton2.Checked || radioButton3.Checked)
    {

        Form3 objd = new Form3(tp, m, l);
        objd.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else if (!radioButton3.Checked && !radioButton2.Checked && !radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select any class");
    }
}
```

I have these if statements in buttons click event when its debug and one of the radiobutton is checked even then messagebox is showing it ain't showing form 3 
I wonder maybe it's some problem with "||" or operator

Comment: A problem with `||` is *extremely* unlikely: start by checking the values of the three button's `Checked` property at the start of the function in a debugger (or via logging).

Comment: Precisely this ^. You most definitely won't find an issue with a core language operator.

Answer (score 0):

Add logs \Trace points(Right click insert trace point use {member you want to print to screen}) with the evaluation result of each part of the condition
and the entire condition result after that.
I believe the answer would reveal itself :).

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and it works fine for me

replaced

```
Form3 objd = new Form3(tp, m, l);
```

with

```
Form objd=new Form();
```

better add a breakpoint then run

Comment: actually i dont know but whenever i cut and paste the first if statement and debugs it works but later on again it always shows the messagebox its too strange , i have almost spent whole day in solving it , still didnt find any solutiion

Comment: @AliAhmed replace Form3 objd = new Form3(tp, m, l); with Form objd=new Form(); then check is that fine